# spring framework schedule annotation problem

Tags: spring

I have several scheduled task in spring application like below:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 30 11 4 * ?")
@Scheduled(cron="0 30 11 * * *")
```

The first one started normally but the second one never start. Is 
spring scheduled task allow multiple concurrent task running.
Or task wont start event scheduled time is up if another task is 
running?

Thanks,

Comment: **Task won't start even scheduled time is up if another task is running of the same scheduled function.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do some google and just found the answer.

Default thread pool for scheduler is only ONE thread, so one task is running and the other must wait for available thread.

The solution is increasing thread pool size for scheduler. I follow [this link](https://www.netjstech.com/2018/10/spring-job-scheduling-using-taskscheduler-scheduled-annotation.html) which use java configuration to increase thread pool size. Spring document has example for xml configuration.

Hope this helps.